# Android Gradle Experimental & RenderScript implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, renderscript, gradle-experimental

I'm trying to use Gradle Experimental.
As of now I don't seem to find a way to implement RenderScript Support Library that I need for blur effects:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis

This is the library I try to use : https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur

But since there is no jar or aar, I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The Readme of the project says that you have to download it first. You can do it cloning the git repo with: `git clone https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur.git`, or you can download it directly from https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur/archive/master.zip

After that, you have to import the project from Android Studio, and follow the usage steps of the library.

Comment: Bly me ... this project is very old ?? it uses `Gradle 0.8.++` and `gradle-1.10` in `graddle-wrapper.properties`  which is obviously incompatible with Android Studio 1.5 (stable). I tried using the required version which is `1.5.0` and I cannot compile at all... this is the error I get : `Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'android-stackblur' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.`